# Superimposing multiple parts on a mesh

Tags: mesh

I have a territory on which I would like to impose a low poly path, but because of the terrain I can't do it. The tile should go at angles - completely repeating the relief, while I do not need to increase the number of vertices on the tile.
[image: Text]
[image: Text]